# How to delete a specific data based on the given ID on the MUI datagrid using firebase real-time as the database

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, mui-x-data-grid

I want to delete a specific data from the MUI `Datagrid`. Which each data on the `Datagrid`is specified by an ID that is incremented every time there is a new data on the database through this code:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]); // holds the data from the database

<DataGrid
rows={userData.map((user, index) => { // the rows are the data from the database
return { ...user, id: index + 1 }; // add ID each row
})}
columns={userColumns.concat(actionColumn)}
pageSize={5}
rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
/>
```

The columns are separated in an array of objects:

```
export const userColumns = [
    {
        field: "id",
        headerName: "ID",
        width: 100,
    },

    {
        field: "name",
        headerName: "Name",
        width: 150,
    },

    {
        field: "number",
        headerName: "Number",
        width: 120,
    },
];
```

This is the `actionColumn` that concatenates the `View`, `Edit`, and `Delete` button to the `userColumns`

```
const actionColumn = [
    {
        field: "action",
        headerName: "Action",
        width: 200,
        renderCell: (params) => {
            return (
                <>
                    <div className="cellAction">
                        <Link to={"/users/" + params.row.id}>
                            <button className="viewButton">View</button>
                        </Link>
                        <button className="deleteButton" onClick={() => handleDelete(params.row.id)}>
                            Delete
                        </button>
                        <Link to={"/users/" + params.row.id}>
                            <button className="editButton"> Edit</button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </>
            );
        },
    },
];
```

I started to work first on handling the delete function. Because I knew if the `delete` function would work, then I can get the idea of getting a specific ID for the `edit` and `view`. However, my delete function seems not working as expected to delete a specific data on the database and on the datagrid itself.

This is what I've tried on the `handleDelete` function. I can verify that each data has their own `id` by logging it out. But, when I log out the `userRef` that suppose holds the `users` database attached by its `id`, it returns an object like this:

[image]

```
const handleDelete = (id) => {
    console.log(id); // display the id
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this user?")) {
        const userRef = ref(db, `/users/${id}`);
        console.log(userRef); // supposed to display the specified user
        console.log(`/users/${id}`) 
        remove(userRef) // delete the specified data on database
            .then(() => {
                setUserData(userData.filter((user) => user.id !== id)); // delete specified data on datagrid
                toast.success("User deleted successfully");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                toast.error(error.message);
            });
    }
};
```

Logging out the `users/${id}` shows `users/1`. It shows the name of the database and the ID from the specified by the datagrid. But, my users database only have unique ID's generated by the firebase. Although, I assume this would still work as I didn't encounter any problems when using HTML tables. Here's an example of my users database below.
[image: users database]

Quite new in react, comments and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption here is incorrect:

```
const userRef = ref(db, `/users/${id}`);
console.log(userRef); // supposed to display the specified user
```

A reference to a node in the database does **not** yet contain a snapshot of the data from the database. If you want to get the data, you first have to [read it from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once).

---

That said, you don't need to read the data in order to be able to delete. All you need to delete a node is the exact path to that node. So if your code doesn't delete the node you want to delete, I recommend logging the path and checking of that matches with the path in your database:

```
console.log(`/users/${id}`);
```

Comment: When logging the `/users${id}` it shows `/users/1`. It gets the database and the id number  based on the datagrid. However, my users database don't have a property of id, only have unique ID's generated by the firebase. Only, the datagrid itself specifies the ID on each row. I assume this would still work as I didn't encounter a problem when using HTML tables. [image of users database](https://paste.pics/0992115db0d2484c86922203df270f84)

Comment: It seems in that case that you need to keep those keys when you read that data from the database, and apply that in `handleDelete` rather than the index that you seem to use now. I don't see how you load the data from the database at first glance, so it's hard to say more.